# how can I get the content generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, capybara

I want to use capybara to fetch the content of  a remote site which has a list and the content of the list was generated by javascript  how can I get these content?
    require "capybara"
    require "capybara/mechanize"
    require "capybara-webkit"
    require "ko_spider/proxy/proxy"

```
module KoSpider
  class CoreSpider
    include Capybara::DSL
    def initialize(wait=10)
        proxy = Proxy.new
        Capybara.configure do |conf|
            conf.run_server              = false
            conf.app                     = ''
            conf.javascript_driver       = :webkit
            conf.default_driver          = :mechanize
            conf.current_driver          = :mechanize
            conf.default_wait_time       = wait        
            conf.ignore_hidden_elements  = false
            conf.current_session.driver.browser.agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
            conf.current_session.driver.browser.agent.set_proxy(proxy.host,proxy.port)
        end
        super()
    end


    def get_proxy_by_url(url)
        visit(url)
        page.all(:css, 'table.tb tbody tr').each do |tr|
            host = ''
            port = ''
            tr.all('td').each_with_index do |td,idx|
                host = td.text if idx == 1
                port = td.text if idx == 2
            end
            puts "=========#{host}:#{port}==========="
        end
    end

  end
end
```

and I want to get the host and the port use the method get_proxy_by_url  at [this page](http://pachong.org/area/short/name/cn/type/high.html)  but at the colums of port  all of them was generated by javascripts   how can I get them

As you can see, in the get_proxy_by_url method I try to get the text of the port  but I can't get those, and I want to know if the capybara can get them

Comment: Please show code that you've written so far

Comment: You gonna need to be more specific, no one can help you based on your question.